# AngularJS not Loading in for one of my pages

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

All links work correctly but the angular app isnt loading on the "my circuits" page. The angular bindings are showing up as defined `{{project.project}}` and so on. What did i not include?

index page:

```
<div class="col-md-1">

    <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">

      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home pull-left"></span> My Circuits</a>
      <a href="#allcircuits" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list pull-left"></span> All Circuits</a>
      <a href="#metrics" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats pull-left"></span>Metrics</a>
      <a href="#export" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-export pull-left"></span>Export Projects</a>
      <a href="#swi" class="btn btn-primary " role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book pull-left"></span> SWIs</a>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="col-md-11">

  <div class = 'ng-view'></div>

</div>

</div>
```

mycircuits

```
<div role="toolbar">
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="projectFilter = ''"><strong>All Projects</strong></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-repeat="project in projects" ng-click="setFilter(project.PROJECT)"><strong>{{project.PROJECT}}</strong></button>
```

Comment: look like there is problem with your angularjs code or the way you added then in sequence wise

Comment: You state that the other links work, just not "My Circuits". The other links have a value after the # token. The "My Circuits" link is just '#' which will need the be set up as the default route.

Comment: @CHouse92 Can you show the logs in your browser's console?

Comment: the my circuits page loads but where things should be they are still saying {{projects.projects}} and so on

Comment: Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.<div class="ng-view ng-scope">

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned ng-app , there is a sequence required... you have to tell the scope first then you can use project.Project , that too if its there in it.

this will give u a better understanding

```
 `http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview`
```

Comment: in your example you never use ng-app, you did not use the correct link

Comment: i have ng-app earlier in the index page

Comment: Can you share the full source as its unclear where have you defined project controller etc ? i am sure that you are missing something , and the error you mentioned above is because of that,the error happens when you have Bad declarations , 

check this
http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/750333-ie-syntax-error-80020101-undefined-array